# Strange situation with Rails (Ruby) randomization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

OK, so I have this in my app's controller:

```
class KalendarController < ApplicationController


  def next
      @joke = Joke.find_by(id: rand(1..Joke.count))
  end

  def show
      #random_id = Joke.all.sample
      #@l = Joke.find_by(id: rand(1..Joke.count))
      #@l = Joke.find_by_id(@l)
      @l = Joke.all.sample

      @t = Time.now.strftime("%A")
      @week = Date.today.cweek % 2 == 0 ? "#{trans} " "PARZYSTY" : "NIEPARZYSTY"
    end

  def trans
    days = ["Niedziela", "Poniedziałek", "Wtorek", "Środa", "Czwartek", "Piątek", "Sobota"]
    @t = Date.today.wday
    days[@t]
  end
 end
```

With a migration file that initially was:

```
class CreateJokes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :jokes do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.string :author

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Later I realised I'd need jokes longer than 255 characters so I made another migration below:

```
class ChangeJokeContentFromStringToText < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :jokes, :content, :text
  end
end
```

Before, I had the 2nd migration I had 3 jokes, with lengths less than 255 characters. But I realised that my random function NEVER picks randomises the joke with the `text` type. Sometimes when i refresh the whole page I see the `text` (longer than 255) joke first, but on clicking several times it never ranodmises the longer joke anymore. Only just the ones that are less than 255 characters. Can someone please explain why this is so and help me fix it?

My view looks like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <div class="container">
        <div id="div1" style= "display:none;"><h1><%= @week %> </h1></div>


        <center><h6>Dzisiaj jest: <span class="label label-info"><%= Time.now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></span><iframe class="pull-right" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPWr-Kalendarz%2F622999367760849&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=false&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></h6></center>

      <div>
      <blockquote class="pull-left">
      <p id="joke_section">
      <%= @l.content %>
      </p>
      <small id="author"><%= @l.author %> </small>


      <%= button_to random_joke_path, {remote: true, class: "btn btn-small"} do %>
       Następny <i class="icon-play"></i>
      <% end %>
      </blockquote>
      </div>

      </div>

</div>
```

In the Rails server I see

```
Started POST "/jokes/next" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-15 02:03:20 +0100
Processing by KalendarController#next as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Vez+9or3fyhLbrqylLfh8lvu21a9iTsVTZA9chqAQkk="}
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jokes"
  Joke Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "jokes".* FROM "jokes" WHERE "jokes"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered kalendar/next.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

That `joke id` is for a joke that's more than 255 characters. but then in the view the joke with `id: 3` shows instead! What's going on?

Comment: I don't think `Joke.all.sample` returns an integer id. It returns a `Joke`.  Therefore your `find` calls are redundant.  Not sure if this is the problem, but it should be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why! In `postgresql` if I added a `joke` (database model) that had `content` that looked something like this:

```
Na lekcji biologi pani pyta Jasia:
- Jasiu z czego składa się serce?
Na to Jasiu:
- z dwóch komor, dwóch przedsionków i nóżek
Na to zdziwiona pani:
- jak to z nóżek?
Jasiu tłumaczy:
- no w nocy słyszałem jak tata mówi: "serduszko rozłóż nóżki"
```

Meaning content witih newlines `\n`, even though in the server the random function picks this joke's `id`, the joke failed to show! But if I changed this same joke to look like this:

```
Na lekcji biologi pani pyta Jasia: - Jasiu z czego składa się serce? Na to Jasiu:- z dwóch komor, dwóch przedsionków i nóżek. Na to zdziwiona pani:- jak to z nóżek? Jasiu tłumaczy:- no w nocy słyszałem jak tata mówi: \"serduszko rozłóż nóżki\"
```

Then the joke shows with no problem when randomised. :D. BTW, the joke table has a column called `content` which is of type `text` meaning this is how I generated it in Rails.
`rails g model joke content:text author:string`

Comment: put "v" agains your answer

Comment: No, there is the sign of "v" on the left side of your answer under the number of likes, and arrows. Just click it

Comment: i see. you mean the "tick" sign. i can't do that till tomorrow.

Comment: Strangely, I did it as I wanted